# Sort an array of string using "random.shuffle" list indice not nonetype error

Tags: python, sorting, arraylist, random

I'm having problems with random in this problem, the console returns error in line: 201 the error is: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType

```
import random
array_Ordem = []
i = int(1)
while i <= 4:
    array_Ordem.append(input('Digite o nome do aluno da apresentação: '))
    i = i + 1
print('A ordem da apresentação será: {}'.format(array_Ordem[random.shuffle(array_Ordem)]))
```

Comment: Please remove the all-caps from your posts. Don't yell at us.

Answer (score 2):

`random.shuffle` returns `None`. When you pass in a list, it gets shuffled in place. Replace this line:

```
print('A ordem da apresentação será: {}'.format(array_Ordem[random.shuffle(array_Ordem)]))
```

With these lines:

```
random.shuffle(array_Ordem)
print('A ordem da apresentação será: {}'.format(array_Ordem))
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! It was a great help